# File Upload With React & .Net Core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, form-data

I am trying to upload files it seems that the file is not getting parsed to the server/back end as the result in the back end for the file is null. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as things seem to be fine. Please see my back-end code as well as the front-end code:
Back-End Code

```
[HttpPost("{projectId}/upload")]
        //[Authorize]
        [ProducesResponseType(204)]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDocument(int projectId, [FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Inside UploadDocument endpoint");

            // Check if project exists
            var project = await _context.Projects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);

            if (project == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"An item in Project could not be found with ID: {projectId}");
                throw new NotFoundException($"An item in Project could not be found with ID: {projectId}");
            }

            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                // Get project folder path
                //var repositoryPath = @"G:\Shares\GT Repository";
                var repositoryPath = @"D:\Uploads";
                var projectFolderPath = Path.Combine(repositoryPath, project.ProjectNumber);
                //var projectFolderPath = Path.Combine(repositoryPath);

                // Creates sub folders >>> future implementation

                if (!Directory.Exists(projectFolderPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(projectFolderPath);

                    // Create subfolders for document types
                    var documentFolders = new List<string>
                    {
                        "Quote",
                        "Customer PO",
                        "Invoice",
                        "Job Card",
                        "Delivery Note",
                        "Costing Sheet"
                    };

                    foreach (var folderName in documentFolders)
                    {
                        var documentFolderPath = Path.Combine(projectFolderPath, folderName);

                        if (!Directory.Exists(documentFolderPath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(documentFolderPath);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Generate a unique file name
                var uniqueFileName = project.ProjectNumber + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;
                //var uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;

                var filePath = Path.Combine(projectFolderPath, uniqueFileName);

                using(var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                return NoContent();
            }

            _logger.LogError("No file provided for upload.");
            throw new BadRequestException("No file provided for upload.");
        }
```

Front-End COde:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState({
    quote: null,
    po: null,
    invoice: null,
    jobCard: null,
    deliveryNote: null,
    costingSheet: null
  })

const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const { name, files } = e.target;

    setFile({
      ...file,
      [name]: files[0],
    });

  };


if(file){
      const formData = new FormData();

      for (const name in file) {
        const uploadedFile = file;
        if (uploadedFile) {
          formData.append(name, uploadedFile);

          console.log(uploadedFile)

          try{

            const result = await axios.post(`https://localhost:7281/api/Project/${values.projectId}/upload`, formData, {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                Accept: "application/json",
              },
            })

            console.log(result);
          }catch(error){
            console.log("Error occurred: ",error);
          }
        }
      }
    }

<input
                className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 mb-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                id="quote"
                name="quote"
                type="file"
                accept="application/pdf"
                title="Attach Quote"
                onChange={handleFileChange}
              />

<input
                className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-1 mb-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                id="po"
                name="po"
                type="file"
                accept="application/pdf"
                title="Attach PO"
                onChange={handleFileChange}
              />

<div className="flex justify-evenly mt-3">
            <div>
                <label className="ml-2" htmlFor="jobCard">Attach Job Card</label>
                <input
                  id="jobCard"
                  name="jobCard"
                  className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                  type="file"
                  accept="application/pdf"
                  title="Attach Job Card"
                  onChange={handleFileChange}
                />
            </div>
                <div>
                  <label className="ml-2" htmlFor="deliveryNote">Attach Delivery Note</label>
                  <input
                    id="deliveryNote"
                    name="deliveryNote"
                    className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                    type="file"
                    accept="application/pdf"
                    title="Attach Delivery Note"
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label className="ml-2" htmlFor="costingSheet">Attach Costing Sheet</label>
                  <input
                    id="costingSheet"
                    name="costingSheet"
                    className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                    type="file"
                    accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    title="Attach Costing Sheet"
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                  />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Adding console logs shows the file and its data and inspecting the network tab via payload shows the file values too but the file does not get parsed to the server, formData returns an empty object which results in the fle being null in the back end

Comment: I tested with your axios call but is able to get the file at back-end. Do you mean your api get called but only receive null value?

Comment: @QiangFu Yes that's true but on the back end it receives null, upon further inspection and uploading a file directly via the back end I saw the name attribute is actually 'file' and not of the names I have given for the input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formData syntax should be `formData.append(paraName,file,filename)`  where the paraName is same as back-end. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#syntax

[image]

You could try following code which works on test.
Add CORS policy at webapi backend. (sometimes it cause problem)

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod();
}));
```

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Front end call test.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const FileUpload = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState([]);    //define list instead
  
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    setFile([...file,e.target.files[0]])      //append the file list
    };

  const importFile= async (e) => {

    console.log(file);   //check all files

    for (const uploadedFile of file){
      if (uploadedFile) {
        const formData = new FormData();      //make a bew FormData for every file.
        formData.append("file",uploadedFile,uploadedFile.name);

        try {
          const res = await axios.post("https://localhost:7161/1/importfile", formData, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              Accept: "application/json",
            },
          });
        } catch (ex) {
          console.log(ex);
        }
  };}}
    

  return  (
    <>
    <input
                // className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 mb-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                id="quote"
                name="quote"
                type="file"
                accept="application/pdf"
                title="Attach Quote"
                onChange={handleFileChange}
              />

<input
                // className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-1 mb-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                id="po"
                name="po"
                type="file"
                accept="application/pdf"
                title="Attach PO"
                onChange={handleFileChange}
              />

<div className="flex justify-evenly mt-3">
            <div>
                <label className="ml-2" htmlFor="jobCard">Attach Job Card</label>
                <input
                  id="jobCard"
                  name="jobCard"
                  //className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                  type="file"
                  accept="application/pdf"
                  title="Attach Job Card"
                  onChange={handleFileChange}
                />
            </div>
                <div>
                  <label className="ml-2" htmlFor="deliveryNote">Attach Delivery Note</label>
                  <input
                    id="deliveryNote"
                    name="deliveryNote"
                    //className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                    type="file"
                    accept="application/pdf"
                    title="Attach Delivery Note"
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label className="ml-2" htmlFor="costingSheet">Attach Costing Sheet</label>
                  <input
                    id="costingSheet"
                    name="costingSheet"
                    //className={`w-full md:w-full px-2 md:mb-0 block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mt-2 ${fileStyles.customFileInput}`}
                    type="file"
                    accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    title="Attach Costing Sheet"
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                  />
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="button" value="upload" onClick={importFile} />

    </>
  )
    
};
```

Test result
[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, this seems what it was missing, cos on my side I could only upload on file from one input at a time, and it was challenging to figure out